# react-dates library's render issue for most of the components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dates

I am trying to use airbnb's **react-dates** on my project. You can get the project here

https://codesandbox.io/s/react-date-nufy9?file=/src/App.js

I am following the documentation of react-dates, but somehow my app fails when I use react-dates's component. I was only able to render when I used `DateRangePicker`. All other components like `DayPickerRangeController` and `PresetDateRangePicker` giving me this error

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.
> Check the render method of `App`.

I need to use `DayPickerRangeController` and `PresetDateRangePicker`. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the sandbox you provided - you are getting this error because you are trying to import `DayPickerRangeControllerWrapper` which is not something that is exported from `react-dates`.

Your sandbox seems to work fine if you import `DayPickerRangeController` instead of `DayPickerRangeControllerWrapper`:
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-date-forked-cms7c?file=/src/App.js